# Silverlight 4.0 : How to acces to the strings of the ApplicationStrings file through the ResourceWrapper in a business application?

Tags: silverlight, string, resources, wrapper

I want to acces to the strings of the ApplicationStrings file through the ResourceWrapper like this :

String loginlabel = ( (ResourceWrapper) App.Current.Resources["ResourceWrapper"] ).ApplicationStrings.LoginLabel;

in order to get the good string according to the current culture (language) but it doesn't work at all.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Compilation error : " Member 'MyApplication.ApplicationStrings.LoginLabel.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. "

I don't really understand what that means...

Comment: And I can not write something like "ApplicationStrings.LoginLabel" because, if I dynamically change the culture during the runtime, this code will always return the string according to the start-up culture of the aplication...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [check this link](http://johnlivingstontech.blogspot.com/2010/02/localizing-resources-in-silverlight.html). It may help.

There you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on a ResourceWrapper so that the app will know when a culture changes.

Note: yeah, I realize this is almost a year old question.